# bit.ly API thumbnails

Tags: api, bit.ly

The bit.ly info API returns URLs for thumbnail images.  When I attempt to access these images, I receive an access denied error.  How do you access the thumbnail images generated by bit.ly?

EDIT:
I am testing the image URL by taking the URL provided by the info API and using the browser to access.  Bit.ly returns an Access Denied error code.  Do I need to somehow provide the login and apikey?

Comment: how are you trying to access those images?

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to tag this as bit.ly so I can follow it but my tag keeps getting reverted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Though you may know this, you can get a list of error codes from this:

http://api.bit.ly/errors?version=2.0.1&login=bitlyapidemo&apiKey=R_0da49e0a9118ff35f52f629d2d71bf07

That might give you some more information, though you'll have to use your apiKey and login:).  As far as I know the thumnails are generated automatically and you should be able to access them via the link generated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bit.ly hosts their thumbnails on Amazon S3 (The Access Denied error is an Amazon error), and it looks like bit.ly has since disabled their access to said thumbnails.